# Codeigniter best way to handle controller calling views

Tags: php, codeigniter

i just want to know if this is a good way in adding fragmented views.

lets say "header.php" is like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Admin Theme v3</title>
    some links..
  </head>
</html>
```

then "body.php" is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    lots of stuff..
  </body>
</html>
```

lastly "scripts.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    some scripts..
  </body>
</html>
```

then in my "MyController.php"

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body');
$this->load->view('scripts');
```

Comment: I see then it cant be done like this. I find this one a much cleaner way but its not good then i guess ill just have to follow your suggestion. One question, what will happen if, as you can see in my example, html tags are redeclared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I find is create a default view.

```
views > default_view.php

views > includes > header_view.php

views > includes > footer_view.php

views > information > contact_view.php
```

On that view

```
<?php

$this->load->view('includes/header_view');

$this->load->view($content_page);

$this->load->view('includes/footer_view');

?>
```

Then on the controller to load view this way you do not have to load the header and footer views all the time.

Following the Codeigniter [StyleGuide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Filename: Example.php

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

   // Add any other variables

   $data['content_page'] = 'information/contact_view'; // This will be your content page example 

   $this->load->view('default_view', $data);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many redundant tag like `<html>`,`<body>` try separate it

header.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Admin Theme v3</title>
  some links..
 </head>
<body>
```

body.php

```
    lots of stuff..
```

scripts.php or footer.php

```
    some scripts..
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good way. Except in some cases (using frames for example), document should have just one declaration and one pair of open/closed html tag.
It could be something like:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Admin Theme v3</title>
        some links..
    </head>
    <body>
```

some_page.php

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            //some stuff and forms here
            </div>
        </div>
```

footer.php

```
        <div class="footer">
        //&copy;2016
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```